# Laravel WhereIn or Wheren with where

Tags: laravel, subquery, where-in

Im trying to design a query, but I have no idea where to start.

I'll type it out how I want it to function.

```
    Items::whereIn('id',$ids)->orWhereIn('id_2',$ids)->where('type','!=',$type)->get();
```

Thats how I want it to work, but I know that wont work, because it will just ignore the WHERE type=$type query, because the whereIN's would have already pulled records, that dont adhere to the Where query.

Basically I want the eloquent version of this...

```
  "SELECT * FROM items WHERE type!=$type AND (id IN (1,2,3) OR id_2 IN(1,2,3))"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are attempting to do is to group statements: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#parameter-grouping

What you need to do is to make the code something like this:

```
Items::where('type', '!=', $type)
  ->where(function ($query) use ($ids) {
      $query->whereIn('id',$ids)
      ->orWhereIn('id_2',$ids);
  })
  ->get();
```

That way you are grouping the where in clauses.

Answer (score 2):

$user_id = 2 ;
$user_ids = [2,3,4,5,6,7,78,87,88,90] ;

where('id',$user_id)  vs   whereIn('id',$user_ids)

Note: where will compare with just first value of array or just one single value. and whereIn will compare evey index of array.

Comment: this is an old question, but I was asking how to do two whereIn's that were chained together.

Answer (score 1):

You're gonna want to do something like this:

```
Item::where('type','!=','ATypeTest')->where(function ($query) {
    $query->whereIn('id',[1, 2, 3])->orWhereIn('id_2',[1, 2, 3]);
})->get();
```

Check the Laravel documentation on more regarding grouping: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#parameter-grouping

This will by the way generate the following SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM "items" WHERE "type" != `ATypeTest` AND ("id" in (1, 2, 3) OR "id_2" in (1, 2, 3))
```